# Path pathology: java no longer working

Tags: osx, environment-variables, java, path

There is some problem with my path which disrupts my java services. The components seem to be in the proper location.

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
```

But the version query no longer works.

```
$ java --version
Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/javac/bin/java" (-1)
$ javac --version
Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/javac/bin/javac" (-1)
```

This result comes after a busy day installing with MacPorts and spack.

*How can this be fixed?*

---

System info:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin ****.***.*** 16.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Here is the PATH setting:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/*******/****/spack/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

Comment: Please check further on the `/usr/bin/java` by doing an `ls -l /usr/bin/java`. On my Linux system, it is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/java`, and it is possible the link is broken. BTW, great title!

Comment: Why did you tag your question [tag:linux] when it's about OSX??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like a problem with `PATH`: you are invoking the `java` utility. The problem is that the front-end `java` executable can't find the rest of the Java installation. I think this is due to the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, which [this thread on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873437/unable-to-locate-an-executable-at-usr-bin-java-bin-java-1) confirms. Check the output of

```
env | grep '^JAVA'
```

If `JAVA_HOME` is set, it must be set to the directory containing subdirectories called `bin` and `jre`. There should be an executable `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`. Typically the last directory component of `JAVA_HOME` contains the substring `jdk`.

Review the places where environment variables are set and correct the setting for `JAVA_HOME`. This may be in `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, ``/.bash_profile`, or some MacPorts or spack file which I don't know about (see also [How do I set environment variables on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x)).